# Python Type 'Instance' Convert

Tags: python

I am using a builtin SNMP library to get some data off a server. Now when I get it back it shows up in a list as

`.>>> [ObjectName(1.2.6.1.4.1.111.1.4.1.7), Integer(21)]`

When I print out `x[0]` (pretend x is that response^) I see 1.2.6.1.4.1.111.1.4.1.7 and 21 for `x[1]` but when I do `type(x[0])` I get `<type 'instance'>`.

Now my question is that is there a way to find the type of `x[1]` and convert it to that? (`x[0]` will always be a string but `x[1]` can be integer, string or float etc.

Is there a way to read that "Integer" (in this case)?

Thanks

Edit:

I dont think I described it clearly. I really done care about `x[0]` at all, I want to convert the `x[1]` to what it is without modifying anything from the class that I am getting the SNMP data from. In this example its an `int` but it can be a float or a string. I am looking for a way to determine what the type of that instance is and then convert it to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `<type 'instance'>` because the library is using [old-style classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html). You can get at the class name by using `x.__class__`. In your example `x[0].__class__.__name__` would be `ObjectName`.

Answer (score 0):

What an object is and what is shown when you print that object are not necessarily related.

Example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'my personal string'
>>>
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> print(f)
my personal string
```

So if you want to know the type of `x[1]` you have to call `type(x[1])`.

And to try to convert `x[0]` to the same type, use:

```
x = [ObjectName(1.2.6.1.4.1.111.1.4.1.7), Integer(21)]
converted = type(x[1])(x[0])
```

Even though if it'll work depends on what `x[0]` and `x[1]` really are.